# Can't pass value from input field daterangepicker - Zeppelin Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-zeppelin, daterangepicker

I have 2 input form fields that use daterangepicker to get single timestamps, I want to pass these to another paragraph after a button is clicked.

This is what the script looks like in para 1,

```
<label class = "name">From Date : </label>
        <input type="text" id="fromDate" class = "dates" placeholder = "Select timestamp" ng-model="fromTs"></input>
<label class = "name">To Date : </label>
        <input type="text" id="toDate" class = "dates" placeholder = "Select timestamp" ng-model="toTs"></input>    
<script>
        $(function() {
            var start = moment();
            var end = moment();
            $('#fromDate').daterangepicker({
                timePicker: true,
                startDate: start,
                singleDatePicker: true,
                showDropdowns: true,
                timePickerSeconds: true,
                timePicker24Hour: true,
                locale: {
                  format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'
                }
            });
            $('#toDate').daterangepicker({
                endDate: end,
                timePicker: true,
                singleDatePicker: true,
                showDropdowns: true,
                timePickerSeconds: true,
                timePicker24Hour: true,
                locale: {
                  format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'
                }
            });
    });
    </script>

<button type="submit" class="btnbtn-primary" ng-click="z.angularBind( 'fromTs', fromDate, 'paragraph_1590566438633_806469898'); z.angularBind('toTs', toTs, 'paragraph_1590566438633_806469898'); z.runParagraph( 'paragraph_1590566438633_806469898');">Apply</button>
```

And this is in para2,

```
%md
### Date range is ${fromTs} to ${toTS}
```

I get `Nullpointer exception` when I run this, checked in the console that there is no object being passed in case of fromTs and toTs.

Initially I was using `bootstrap-datepicker` but later moved to `daterangepicker` as it had the option of selection of time as well, using the ng-model value to pass the input field value worked there, but it doesn't seem to be working with `daterangepicker`.

Why is this happening and how do I go about this error?